# How to call a bash script as a post-deploy trigger with fortrabbit.yml

Tags: deployment, fortrabbit

I'm using the following (excerpt) to run a script after deploy:

```
post-deploy:
    script: bash refresh.sh
```

It never gets called, even though I can run it just fine if I ssh into the machine and execute the same command inside *~/htdocs*.

What can I do to run this or similar scripts (e.g. php deploy.php) after deployment on Fortrabbit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bash script will not work, it must be a php script. However, inside your php script you can call anything using backticks:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: Thanks, Oliver. You might want to add that note to your docs if you haven't done so already :)